# extracting specific lines from a text file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a data in my `.txt`file as below, I want to extract the line that have value as 12 and copy it into new `.txt` file. I tried with `sed` but could get the result, any help would be appreciated . Thanks

```
"944760 1939"   10
"944760 1940"   12
"946120 1940"   2
"946370 1939"   10
"946370 1940"   12
"946460 1940"   6
"946530 1939"   10
```

Comment: `tried with sed` please add that code to question..

Comment: `sed -n '/[^0-9]12$/p' file`

Comment: `grep  ' 12$' inputfile  >newfile`

Comment: Your question suggests you expect to find 1 line with `12`. I think you want both and that the comment of @Cyrus is what you want, can you show your sed-command and discuss what you think about the different suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

Why don't just search forum, before posting here, so many posts repeated

```
awk '$3 == 12' infile > outfile
```

which is same as

```
awk '$3 == 12 { print }' infile > outfile
```

**Explanation**

- `$3 == 12` if 3rd column is equal to 12, print such record/row

Answer (score 5):

Following simple `awk` may help you on same:

```
awk '$NF==12{print $0 > "new_file"}'   Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

`$NF==12`: Checking condition here if last field's value is `12`means condition is TRUE then perform further/following statements.

`{print $0 > "new_file"}`: Printing current line($0) value to a output file named

`new_file`(you could change its name as per your wish too).

`Input_file`: Mentioning Input_file name here.

Solution 3rd: As per karafka sir's comment adding this one too now.

```
awk'$NF==12' Input_file > "new_file"
```

Comment: idiomatic version is `awk '$NF==12' file > newfile`

Comment: @karakfa, thank you sir added it to solution now, thank you for your as usual guidance here.